# Working with public assets throws compilation error

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

When I'm attempting to work with public assets (as documented [here](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.1/Assets)) I'm receiving compilation errors. This is my route and the error it throws:

```
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at("public", file) 
                                                          ^
`)' expected but `"' found
```

Can anyone shed any light on this? Am I using a deprecated method of serving assets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this route as `hotfix`:

```
GET    /assets/*file     controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

*note*: as we can see, the documentation still needs some fixing.

*edit*: For details please check the github/wiki version of the doc, it's debbuged now: http://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/Assets

Comment: Accurate and extensive documentation would make this the perfect framework for me. As it stands I'm sure this wont be my last question! Thanks for your answer again!

Comment: There're some bugs in docs sometimes, fortunately the docs are available for fixing on github - there's also fixed Assets section now: https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/Assets